# ANDROID creates map without clicking

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button strtSrchBtn ;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Chic","Oncreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    strtSrchBtn = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.start_search_btn);
    strtSrchBtn.setTransformationMethod(null);

    strtSrchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Chic","Buton clicked");
            try {
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Log.d("Chic","Map created");
                    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                            findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                }
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                        position(new LatLng(21 , 57)).title("TutorialsPoint"));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}//end of onCreate()
}
```

This is my `mainactivity`.

I only have `activity` class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start_search_btn"
    android:id="@+id/start_search_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:transitionName="@string/abc_capital_off"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I don't want to use any other activity. How can I solve this? When the user clicks, the map fills the screen and the button disappears. Then I am supposed to show the current location and show the nearest hospital.

Answer (score 0):

On button click in your `onClick()` method

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This will make the button invisible and also it will leave the space that was occupied by the button.

Comment: But map comes again at oncreate?

Comment: i want it not to come. Should i use another acitivity?